# What is the most secure way to use AWS S3 to upload documents (meant for certain users based on email/mobile auth) which are mailed to users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 to store order confirmation PDFs. Once a user completes a transaction, the order confirmation PDF is generated and stored in an AWS S3 bucket and then e-mailed as a link to the user. I want to ensure that only the specific user accesses the document meant for him/her. What is the best and most secure way to do this?

I am using a nodejs server to process user requests.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at presigned URLs - they allow you to grant temporary access to specific objects without the user being required to have an AWS account, just by a signed URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript SDK for AWS to get a signed URL from an object on S3. You can find the reference [on this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property). I also recommend setting an expiry date for this URL, to ensure the most security.

```
# From AWS JS SDK docs page
var params = { Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Expires: 60 };

var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);

console.log('The URL is', url); // expires in 60 seconds
```

With a signed URL, you can set the objects on S3 to not be publicly accessible, by changing the permissions on the Bucket itself. See [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access.html) for more information on that.

With this setup, your PDF file won't be accessible by anyone except those that have this signed URL (that you can send on the email to the user).

Answer (score 0):

An [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) provides time-limited access to a private object. Once the time period expires, the object is no longer accessible.

However, the maximum validity period for a pre-signed URL is **7 days**. It is possible that your use-case requires access to the file for longer than this period.

For that you would have two options:

- Require the user to authenticate to your website, then generate a new pre-signed URL, *or*
- Instead of using a pre-signed URL, use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) that will obfuscate the URL and make it difficult to guess -- this is not perfect security, but a long UUID will make it a little more secure